# R renaming predictors in lme

Tags: r, lme4

I set up two identical models in lme (R) and apply it to two different dependent variables. However, in one of the models one of the predictors is renamed, a 1 is added to the name. I assume this means, that the predictor is somehow adjusted, but I do not know what is going on and how to suppress this behaviour? Could you please provide me with some information on this or a hint on where to find help on this topic?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps your predictor is a two-level factor variable and "1" is one of the levels? In this case the other level will not appear because it is included in the intercept, and the coefficient will automatically concatenate the name of the variable and the factor level.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!